# How to calculate rates between observations with R

Tags: r, dplyr

Considering I have a data frame ordered by date and for each one I have some quantities, how can I calculate **X<sub>day</sub> / X<sub>day-1</sub>** index for each row?

My dataset: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/imdevskp/covid_19_jhu_data_web_scrap_and_cleaning/master/covid_19_clean_complete.csv

My processe dataset (R code):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

covid19 <- read.table(file = "covid_19_clean_complete.csv",
                      header = TRUE,
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                      sep = ",",
                      dec = ".",
                      quote = "\"")

covid19$Date <- mdy(covid19$Date)

brasil <- covid19 %>%
    filter(Country.Region == "Brazil") %>%
    group_by(Country.Region, Date) %>%
    summarise(Cases = sum(Confirmed))
```

My rate will be calculated over *Cases* variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can take the `lag` of 'Cases` and use that to divide the 'Cases'

```
library(dplyr)
out <- covid19 %>%
          group_by(Country.Region, Date) %>%
          summarise(Cases = sum(Confirmed)) %>%
          mutate(Ratio = Cases/lag(Cases))
out %>%
   filter(Country.Region == "Brazil") %>%
   tail
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   Country.Region [1]
#  Country.Region Date       Cases Ratio
#  <chr>          <date>     <int> <dbl>
#1 Brazil         2020-03-08    20  1.54
#2 Brazil         2020-03-09    25  1.25
#3 Brazil         2020-03-10    31  1.24
#4 Brazil         2020-03-11    38  1.23
#5 Brazil         2020-03-12    52  1.37
#6 Brazil         2020-03-13   151  2.90
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked well for me. Thanks!